# Send a CNAME Record as Answer of a CNAME DNS query

Tags: node.js, dns

I want to answer to a CNAME Query in my node.js dns server and I want to put my answer section in response's buffer. I have tried this buffer for answer section and tested that with dig module in Windows and got this answer:

```
    ;; Got bad packet: bad label type
    53 bytes
    0d c4 85 80 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 04 74 65 73          .............tes
    74 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 05 00 01 c0 0c 00 05 00 01          t.com...........
    00 00 00 00 00 0a 73 65 63 6f 6e 64 54 65 73 74          ......secondTest
    03 63 6f 6d 00                                           .com.
```

I have sent this buffer to the client as answer section:

```
[170,254,133,128,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,116,101,115,116,3,99,111,109,0,0,5,0,1,192,12,0,5,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,115,101,99,111,110,100,84,101,115,116,3,99,111,109,0]
```

I can't figure that out what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the dig source code at https://salsa.debian.org/dns-team/bind9/blob/debian/master/lib/dns/name.c  you will see that error "bad label type" is `DNS_R_BADLABELTYPE` and happens only if a byte has value 91<sub>10</sub> or any value between 64<sub>10</sub> inclusive and 192<sub>10</sub> because they all denote problems in encoding a name.

From your buffer:

- `0d c4`, a 16 bits ID to identify the message
- `85 80` is `1 0000 1 0 1 1 000 0000` which means:

  - `1`: message is a response
  - `0000`: standard query
  - `1`: AA, Authoritative answer
  - `0`: TC, NOT truncated
  - `1`: RD, Recursion Desired
  - `1`: RA, Recursion Available
  - `000`: Z, must be zeros
  - `0000`: RCODE, no error
- `00 01` QDCOUNT, 1 entry in the question section
- `00 01` ANCOUNT, 1 entry in the answer section
- `00 00` NSCOUNT, 0 entries in the authority section
- `00 00` ARCOUNT, 0 entries in the additional section

Now the question:

- `04` a label of 4 bytes
- `74 65 73 74` which is `test`
- `03` a label of 3 bytes
- `63 6f 6d` which is `com`
- `00` a label of 0 byte, that is root
- `00 05` the type, `CNAME`
- `00 01` the class, `IN`

And now we enter the answer section:

- `c0 0c` means a pointer (first byte has 2 first bits set) to position `0c` that is 13<sub>10</sub>. At that position we find again `test.com` as `74 65 73 74 03 63 6f 6d 00`
- `00 05` the type, `CNAME`
- `00 01` the class, `IN`,
- `00 00 00 00` the TTL, 0
- `00 0a` RDLENGTH, size of following data, 10 bytes
- for the CNAME record type, the RDATA following the RDLENGTH value is again a name
- so the 10 bytes to take into account now are `73 65 63 6f 6e 64 54 65 73 74` the first 1 or 2 bytes should be the size, or a pointer, but 73<sub>16</sub> is 115<sub>10</sub>, hence you arrive in the situation described on top and that leads to the error message, because the byte starts with `01`<sub>2</sub> and RFC  1035 clearly says: "(The 10 and 01 combinations are reserved for future use.)

If you want `test.com. 0 IN CNAME secondTest.com` this should produce the following buffer (without name compression): 
`04 74 65 73 74 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 05 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 10 0a 73 65 63 6f 6e 64 74 65 73 74 03 63 6f 6d 00`

so in fact you need to replace `0,10,115,101,99,111,110,100,84,101,115,116,3,99,111,109,0` by
`0,16,10,115,101,99,111,110,100,116,101,115,116,3,99,111,109,0`

That is you are missing the first `16` byte.
(and the `84` vs `116` difference later on is if you want `T` or `t` in first t of `secondTest`)